# How can I zoom in on a certain region of a BitmapSource in a WPF Image control?

Tags: wpf, image, bitmapsource, rendertransform

Let's say I have a 1280x1024 BitmapSource in a WPF Image control. There is a 100x100 "active" area of this image that I want to be able to zoom in on with a button click. I want to zoom as much as possible while maintaining the aspect ratio and keeping all "active" pixels visible. This is what I have:

XAML:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Zoom" Click="Button_Click" />
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Image Name="TheImage" />
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

Code:

```
private const int WIDTH = 1280;
private const int HEIGHT = 1024;
private const int MIN_X = 100;
private const int MAX_X = 200;
private const int MIN_Y = 100;
private const int MAX_Y = 200;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    byte[] image = new byte[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
    for (int y = MIN_Y; y <= MAX_Y; y++)
        for (int x = MIN_X; x <= MAX_X; x++)
            image[y * WIDTH + x] = byte.MaxValue;
    TheImage.Source = BitmapSource.Create(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Gray8, null, image, WIDTH);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double factor = 1.0 / Math.Max((MAX_X - MIN_X) / (double)WIDTH, (MAX_Y - MIN_Y) / (double)HEIGHT);
    Matrix matrix = Matrix.Identity;
    matrix.ScaleAt(factor, factor, (MIN_X + MAX_X) / 2.0 / WIDTH * TheImage.ActualWidth, (MIN_Y + MAX_Y) / 2.0 / HEIGHT * TheImage.ActualHeight);
    TheImage.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);
}
```

Here is what it looks like before zoom:
[image: before zoom]

And here is after zoom:
[image: after zoom]

It looks like the amount of zoom is correct, but I think the issue is that the center of the scaling should shift due to the scaling, but I'm not sure how to account for that upfront.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The simplest approach seems to be to first do a translation such that the center of the active area is in the center of the image, then do the scaling centered on that:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double factor = 1.0 / Math.Max((MAX_X - MIN_X) / (double)WIDTH, (MAX_Y - MIN_Y) / (double)HEIGHT);
    Matrix matrix = Matrix.Identity;
    matrix.Translate(0.5 * TheImage.ActualWidth - (MIN_X + MAX_X) / 2.0 / WIDTH * TheImage.ActualWidth, 0.5 * TheImage.ActualHeight - (MIN_Y + MAX_Y) / 2.0 / HEIGHT * TheImage.ActualHeight);
    matrix.ScaleAt(factor, factor, 0.5 * TheImage.ActualWidth, 0.5 * TheImage.ActualHeight);
    TheImage.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);
}
```

Screenshot after zoom:
[image: after zoom]